# Caching Headers Interceptor does nothing - struts2

Tags: java, caching, struts2

I'm developing a web application using Struts2. The user logs in, places a request and then logs out.

When the user clicks the 'Back' button(after logging out), the previous logged-in page should not be visible to him which means I want to disallow browser caching. I've added an interceptor for this purpose:

```
public class CachingHeadersInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
        if(response!=null){
            response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

        }

        return invocation.invoke();
    }

}
```

And this entry in the `struts.xml` file :

```
 <interceptors>

       <interceptor name="cachingHeadersInterceptor" class="com.proconsulto.interceptor.CachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
       <interceptor-stack name="defaultSecurityStack">
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
       <interceptor-ref name="cachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
       </interceptor-stack>

       </interceptors>
```

But after logging out when I click on the Back button, I'm still able to access that logged-in page.

What is my code missing here? I've written this code following the tutorials online.

Here is the exception trace:

```
WARNING: Unable to load config class com.proconsulto.interceptor.CachingHeadersInterceptor at interceptor - file:/C:/Users/AnkitaNallana/Desktop/OneMoreTime/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ProConsulto%20-%20Everything%20is%20fine%20-%20v16/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:21:117 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the cachingHeadersInterceptor interceptor
Jul 08, 2014 3:21:26 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Actual exception
Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class com.proconsulto.interceptor.CachingHeadersInterceptor - interceptor - file:/C:/Users/AnkitaNallana/Desktop/OneMoreTime/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ProConsulto%20-%20Everything%20is%20fine%20-%20v16/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:21:117
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(StrutsObjectFactory.java:77)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:70)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:919)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:932)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:955)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:524)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:473)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.proconsulto.interceptor.CachingHeadersInterceptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:108)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(StrutsObjectFactory.java:52)
    ... 26 more
```

To be extra sure I copied & pasted the package & the class name a dozen times, I still don't know why I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException` !

The other method would be writing it as JSP `<% response.setHeader("xxx","vvv") %>` tags on every page. That'd be extremely tedious. I wouldn't want to disable it using JS because that would be bad UX.

I've also noticed another thing. When I did use the `<% response.setHeader("xxx","vvv") %>` tags on a few JSPs, and clicked the 'Back' button, a Reload button would show up (on Chrome) - if you click on it - the login data gets submitted and one can view the logged-in pages again. What can I do so that this login data is not stored for re-submission?

If there's a similar question which I probably may have not come across - please do mention its link in the comment. I could not find an answer so I'm asking here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples always demonstrate better than theory...

**EDIT :** I am just showing you a demo.

```
package com.interceptors;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;

public class CachingHeadersInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

    if (ServletActionContext.getResponse() != null) {
        ServletActionContext.getResponse().setHeader("Cache-control",
                "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        ServletActionContext.getResponse().setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        ServletActionContext.getResponse().setHeader("Expires", "-1");
        ServletActionContext.getResponse().setHeader("Vary", "*");
    }
    return invocation.invoke();
}

}
```

In `struts.xml`

```
<package name="helloworld" namespace="" extends="struts-default">
   <interceptors>
     <interceptor name="cachingHeadersInterceptor" class="com.interceptors.CachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
     <interceptor-stack name="defaultSecurityStack">
         <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
         <interceptor-ref name="cachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
     </interceptor-stack>
   </interceptors>
   <action name="login" class="com.common.LoginAction" >
         <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>          
         <interceptor-ref name="cachingHeadersInterceptor"/>

        <result name="success">/Home.jsp</result>
   </action>
  </package>
```

**Output:** This is in response header

[image: Cache Header Output]

And after logout if you want to block user from viewing page you can implement `Authorizeinterceptor`

Reference : See example of [AuthorizationInterceptor.java](https://github.com/prem30488/RemoteServerManagementSystem/blob/master/src/Interceptors/AuthorizationInterceptor.java)

In this interceptor just check session value for example username which after logout will be null and if null redirect to login.

You can either create new interceptor or can put the below code in same `CachingHeadersInterceptor.java`

```
SessionMap<String,Object> map = (SessionMap<String,Object>) inv.getInvocationContext().getSession();
Object user = map.get("username");  
if(user==null ||user.equals("") || map.isEmpty() || map == null ){  
  return "login";   
}
```

In `struts.xml` Define login as result that redirects to login page.

```
<global-results>
    <result name="login">login.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```

Also see [LoginAction.java](https://github.com/prem30488/RemoteServerManagementSystem/blob/master/src/com.action.common/LoginAction.java) and [LogoutAction.java](https://github.com/prem30488/RemoteServerManagementSystem/blob/master/src/com.action.common/LogoutAction.java) in which I have added and removed **username** from session.

It's Simple.... :)

Comment: Doesn't help - I  am checking the console log now and I'm actually getting a `ClassNotFound` Exception - I don't know why!

Comment: Please refer to example shown. I have used live http header addon for firefox to see what header I get in response. And got header as I have set in interceptor.You can implement this in your project.

Comment: You can check or verify packagename and classname in `struts.xml` for interceptor.

Comment: Thank you. I read up a bit more on Interceptors and tried out your solution and it works brilliantly for me. But still, 'Confirm Form Submission' automatically logs me in :( Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I did not understand with your `Confirm Form Submission`. Please explain me the scenario. But I think you need to read a little bit about struts tokens. Struts tokens are used to prevent the same page from refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put below in your html head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="No-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Mean while make sure you have removed session after logout.

Comment: Yes, I've removed all sessions and have invalidated it after logout. Adding meta tags to each and every page would be tedious, no?

Comment: Aren't you using struts 2 tiles ?! It will help you to put your common files in one jsp page.

Comment: Um no.. I wasn't aware of struts2 tiles